# Button Link To Website Doesn't Work

Tags: android, button

I have 2 buttons, one going to a Twitter URL and one to the Play Store URL.
The Twitter one works yet the Play Store button doesn't.
Code is below.

```
  //TWITTER BUTTON
    Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwitter);
    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sendToTwitter();
        }
    });
}
            protected void sendToTwitter() {
                    String url = "http://twitter.com/neilk27";
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
                    startActivity(i);

    //DONATE BUTTON    
    Button bd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDonate);
    bd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    sendToStore();
            }
        });
    }
                protected void sendToStore() {
                        String url1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=NK+Apps";
                        Intent i1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i1.setData(Uri.parse(url1)); 
                        startActivity(i1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but your curly braces seems to be causing some problems.
Try this :

```
Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTwitter);
bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendToTwitter();
    }
});
protected void sendToTwitter() {
    String url = "http://twitter.com/neilk27";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url)); 
    startActivity(i);
}
//DONATE BUTTON    
Button bd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDonate);
bd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        sendToStore();
    }
});
protected void sendToStore() {
    String url1 = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=NK+Apps";
    Intent i1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i1.setData(Uri.parse(url1)); 
    startActivity(i1);
}
```